# MFTF magento test failed

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, mtf

I am getting extension back from market place because of having the MTFT test failes

From summary the following two test cases are failed

```
 {
     "AdminCreateAndEditConfigurableProductSettingsTest": {
     "status": "failed",
     "exit_code": 1
  }

 "StorefrontCustomerCheckoutTest": {
       "status": "failed",
        "exit_code": 1
   }
```

I changes the configurable poduct settings from backend and also perform a checkout as a customer everything is working fine I don't know what's the reason for getting this kind of errors.
Need Some Suggestions/guidence to resolve this, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please explain more, and which module did you get an error in?

Comment: I am getting this error while submitting my custom extension to market place, I t fails MFTF testing